# Index a JSON file into elasticsearch command/mapping errors

Tags: json, elasticsearch, mapping, kibana

I'm new to ELK and I want to import a JSON file into Elasticsearch. this is my file:

```
{
"news":{
  "1":{
     "_score":1.0,
     "_index":"newsvit",
     "_source":{
        "content":" \u0641\u0647\u06cc\u0645\u0647 \u062d\u0633\u0646\u200c\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06cc: \u0627\u06af\u0631\u0686\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u0647\u06cc\u0627\u0647\u0648\u06cc \u0627\u0646\u062a\u062e\u0627\u0628\u0627\u062a \u0631\u06cc\u0627\u0633\u062a \u062c\u0645\u0647\u0648\u0631\u06cc\u060c \u0645\u0648\u0636\u0648\u0639\u06cc \u0645\u0627\u0646\u0646\u062f \u0645\u0639\u0631\u0641\u06cc \u06a9\u0627\u0646\u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0627\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0634\u0648\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0634\u0647\u0631 \u062f\u0631 \u062d\u0627\u0634\u06cc\u0647 \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631 \u06af\u0631\u0641\u062a\u0647\u060c \u0627\u0645\u0627 \u0627\u0645\u0633\u0627\u0644 \u0628\u0647 \u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u067e\u0646\u062c\u0645\u06cc\u0646 \u062f\u0648\u0631\u0647 \u0627\u0646\u062a\u062e\u0627\u0628 \u0627\u0639\u0636\u0627\u06cc \u0634\u0648\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0634\u0647\u0631\u060c \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0631\u0648\u06cc\u062f\u0627\u062f \u0628\u0647 \u0646\u0633\u0628\u062a \u062f\u0648\u0631\u0647\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0642\u0628\u0644\u060c \u0628\u06cc\u0634\u062a\u0631 \u0645\u0648\u0631\u062f \u062a\u0648\u062c\u0647 \u0648\u0627\u0642\u0639 \u0634\u062f\u0647. \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0627\u0642\u0628\u0627\u0644\u060c \u0686\u0647 \u0627\u0632 \u0633\u0648\u06cc \u0686\u0647\u0631\u0647\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u0637\u0631\u062d \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u062b\u0628\u062a \u0646\u0627\u0645 \u0648 \u0686\u0647 \u0627\u0632 \u0633\u0648\u06cc \u0645\u0631\u062f\u0645 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0645\u0634\u0627\u0631\u06a9\u062a \u062f\u0631 \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0631\u0648\u06cc\u062f\u0627\u062f\u060c \u0639\u0644\u062a\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u06af\u0648\u0646\u0627\u06af\u0648\u0646\u06cc \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u062f \u062f\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0634\u062f \u06a9\u0647 \u062a\u0648\u062c\u0647 \u0628\u0647 \u0622\u0646\u060c \u0645\u06cc\u200c\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0646\u062f \u0631\u0627\u0647\u06af\u0634\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u0639\u0636\u0627\u06cc \u0631\u06",
        "lead":"\u062c\u0627\u0645\u0639\u0647&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;\u0634\u0647\u0631\u06cc - \u0645\u06cc\u0632\u06af\u0631\u062f\u06cc \u062f\u0631\u0628\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0639\u0645\u0644\u06a9\u0631\u062f \u062f\u0648\u0631\u0647\u200c\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u06af\u0630\u0634\u062a\u0647 \u0634\u0648\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0634\u0647\u0631\u060c \u0622\u0646\u0686\u0647 \u0627\u0639\u0636\u0627\u06cc \u062c\u062f\u06cc\u062f \u0628\u0627\u06cc\u062f \u0645\u062f \u0646\u0638\u0631 \u062f\u0627\u0634\u062a\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0634\u0646\u062f \u0648 \u0647\u0645\u0686\u0646\u06cc\u0646 \u0645\u0627\u0647\u06cc\u062a \u0633\u06cc\u0627\u0633\u06cc \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0646 \u06cc\u0627 \u0646\u0628\u0648\u062f\u0646 \u0634\u0648\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0634\u0647\u0631.",
        "agency":"13",
        "date_created":1494518193,
        "url":"http://www.khabaronline.ir/(X(1)S(bud4wg3ebzbxv51mj45iwjtp))/detail/663749/society/urban",
        "image":"uploads/2017/05/11/1589793661.jpg",
        "category":"15"
     },
     "_type":"news",
     "_id":"2981643"
  },
  "2": {
...
```

based on what I have learnt, at first, I tried to create a mapping system for it in DevTools of Kibana. I want to be able to perform queries and search on this file based on fields in `_source`, such as category, id and so on. this is my mapping:

```
PUT /main-news-test-data
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "_score": {"type":"integer"},
      "_index": {"type":"keyword"},
      "_type":{"type":"keyword"},
      "_id":{"type":"keyword"} 
    },
    "_source":{
      "properties": {
       "content":{"type":"text"},
        "title":{"type":"text"},
        "lead":{"type":"text"},
        "agency":{"type":"keyword"},
        "date_created":{"type":"date"},
        "url":{"type":"keyword"},
        "image":{"type":"keyword"},
        "category":{"type":"keyword"}
       }
      }
  }
}

HEAD main-news-test-data

GET /main-news-test-data/_search?q=*
```

but when I run this in Devtools I receive this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Mapping definition for [_source] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {image={type=keyword}, agency={type=keyword}, date_created={type=date}, title={type=text}, category={type=keyword}, content={type=text}, lead={type=text}, url={type=keyword}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [_source] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {image={type=keyword}, agency={type=keyword}, date_created={type=date}, title={type=text}, category={type=keyword}, content={type=text}, lead={type=text}, url={type=keyword}}]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Mapping definition for [_source] has unsupported parameters:  [properties : {image={type=keyword}, agency={type=keyword}, date_created={type=date}, title={type=text}, category={type=keyword}, content={type=text}, lead={type=text}, url={type=keyword}}]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I also tried to index my file into elasticsearch using this PowerShell command afterwards:

```
Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:9200/main-news-test-data/doc/_bulk?pretty" -Method Post -ContentType 'application/x-ndjson' -InFile "test.json"
```

but again I get this error from Powershell:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "json_e_o_f_exception",
        "reason" : "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source:
(org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 1, column: 1])\n at
[Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 2, column: 1]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "json_e_o_f_exception",
    "reason" : "Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source:
(org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 1, column: 1])\n at
[Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper); line: 2, column: 1]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

So what should I do? how do I import a JSON file into elasticsearch that is queryable by fields?

Answer (score 0):

with what I read I can say that :

your mapping is strange
Just put :

```
PUT /main-news-test-data
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lead": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "agency": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "date_created": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "image": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your Json is wrong. A bulk don't use a valid json.
A file for the _bulk api will look like this :

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "main-news-test-data", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "main-news-test-data", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "field1" : "value2" }
```

Please also Note that  "_score":1.0, has no reason to be in your request and that _type is deprecated (if you use a 7.0+, _type can only be _doc and should be ignored)